# Sagemaker Error for HyperParameterTuning job

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I checked the aws forums and here at SO and I can't find a solution to this error or an explanation to what it is.

The full error is:

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for HyperParameterTuning job sagemaker-xgboost-200330-1544: Failed. Reason: No objective metrics found after running 5 training jobs. Please ensure that the custom algorithm is emitting the objective metric as defined by the regular expression provided.
```

and it is respective to the following code:

```
xgbt = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container, #name of training container
                                    role, # IAM role to use
                                    train_instance_count = 1, # number of instances yo use for training
                                    train_instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge', #type of virtual machine to use
                                    output_path = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(session.default_bucket(),
                                                                            prefix),
                                    sagemaker_session = session) #current sagemaker session


xgbt.set_hyperparameters(
    max_depth = 5,
    eta = 0.1,
    eval_metric='auc',
    objective='binary:logistic',
    early_stopping_rounds=500,
    rate_drop=0.1,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    subsample=0.75,
    min_child_weight=0,
    num_round = 500)


xgbt.fit({'train': s3_input_train})
```

and then the hyperparameter tuning is where it croaks:

```
from sagemaker.tuner import IntegerParameter, ContinuousParameter, HyperparameterTuner

xgb_hyperparameter_tuner = HyperparameterTuner(estimator = xgbt, # The estimator object to use as the basis for the training jobs.
                                               objective_metric_name = 'validation:auc', # The metric used to compare trained models.
                                               objective_type = 'Maximize', # Whether we wish to minimize or maximize the metric.
                                               max_jobs = 20, # The total number of models to train
                                               max_parallel_jobs = 3, # The number of models to train in parallel
                                               hyperparameter_ranges = {
                                                    'max_depth': IntegerParameter(3, 12),
                                                    'eta'      : ContinuousParameter(0.01, 0.5),
                                                    'min_child_weight': IntegerParameter(2, 8),
                                                    'subsample': ContinuousParameter(0.5, 0.9),
                                                    'gamma': ContinuousParameter(0, 10),
                                               })

xgb_hyperparameter_tuner.fit({'train': s3_input_train})

xgb_hyperparameter_tuner.wait()
```

I think I have the metrics correctly defined so I don't know what it wants from me.

Thank you so much for checking this out.

Comment: in the cloudwatch logs of individual training iteration, can you see the validation auc printed in the logs?

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out, once I added num_round to the hyperparameters it worked.